# set camera relative to point collection

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to set the camera to be 3 units away from a collection of points I would like this to be relative to the group of points since the points will change later on.

So far I can retrieve x,y,z coordinates from the database and are returned using djangos `{{coord_x}}` I will have to return the correct length, (I could do this on the python side - len()) for now the database query is limited to 20 rows. These points are brought into three.js using a for loop.

How do I set a camera relative to the objects? Do I need to calculate a bounding box?

```
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 100000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // allow resizing of the window
    window.addEventListener('resize', function()
    {
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });

    //Controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    //create the shape
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x007654, wireframe: false});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    var numpoints = 20;
    var dots = []; //If you want to use for other task

    for (var i = 0 ; i < numpoints ; i++) {
        var x = "{{coord_x}}";
        var y = "{{coord_y}}";
        var z = "{{coord_z}}";

        // var x = Math.random() * (0 - 1) + 1
        // var y = Math.random() * (0 - 1) + 1
        // var z = Math.random() * (0 - 1) + 1


        var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        dots.push(dotGeometry);
        dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
        var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 3, sizeAttenuation: false, color: 0xFF0000 });
        var dot = new THREE.Points( dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
        scene.add(dot);
    }

    camera.position.z = 30

    //game logic, allow rotation
    var update = function()
    {
      //cube.rotation.x += 0.00;
      //cube.rotation.y += 0.0025;
      //dot.rotation.x += 0.00;
      //dot.rotation.y += 0.005;
    };

    // draw scene
    var render = function()
    {
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
    var GameLoop = function()
    {
      requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

      update();
      render();
    };

    GameLoop();
   </script>
```

Comment: Or compute a bounding sphere.

Comment: Ok, so I assume you mean I need to create a bounding space (box/sphere) and then position the camera relative to the bounding space. Do you know how to do this? I tried some code snippets but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Have a look at this [`.setFromPoints()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere.setFromPoints) method of `THREE.Sphere()`.

Comment: So I'm trying camera.setFromPoints(dots); because I want to set the position of the camera based on the array of dots. Although this doesn't work, and I'm not finding this in the beginner tutorials. Again, sorry for being a noob.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can work with `THREE.Sphere()` object to set the position of your camera:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  geom.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(
      Math.random() - 0.5,
      Math.random() - 0.5,
      Math.random() - 0.5
    ).multiplyScalar(10)
  );
}
var points = new THREE.Points(geom, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.25,
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(points);

var sphere = new THREE.Sphere().setFromPoints(geom.vertices);
console.log(sphere);
camera.position.copy(sphere.center);
camera.position.z += sphere.radius / Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov / 2));

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```